# Defer image and replacement loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function that once the page is loaded swaps the assets from a transparent gif to full images via the data-src below.

```
<img src="1x1.gif" data-src="full-photo.png" class="asset" /> // My image

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    defer_images();

    function defer_images() {
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var imgDefer = document.getElementsByClassName('asset');

        for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
            if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));

                var iWidth = imgDefer[i].naturalWidth; // Check image exists

                if (iWidth) { 
                    loadedImages++; 
                } else {
                    console.log("Image missing: "+imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
                }
            }

            // all images exist and have been replaced

            if (imgDefer.length === loadedImages) {
                doThings();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This seems to work fine on a cached page. But if I reload the page and switch tabs – the code doesn't complete as loadedImages++ is never fired.

I can't use setInterval or setTimeout to re-check as this code is used in DoubleClick.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect that images are loaded by using the `onload` event and failed to load using `onerror`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
    var img = imgDefer[i];
    if (img.getAttribute('data-src')) {
        img.addEventListener("load", function() {
            loadedImages++;
        });
        img.addEventListener("error", function() {
            console.log("Image missing: "+ this.getAttribute("data-src"))
        });
        img.src = img.getAttribute('data-src');
    }
}
```

The reason it fails for non-cached is because it takes time to load the image, and your for loop is fast. Use the events to trigger when the image is loaded.

You can [read more here](https://idiallo.com/javascript/img-detect-loaded).

**Note:** Detecting that all images are loaded may require using promises:

```
function loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
    img.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));
    img.src = src;
    // append to the dom or replace here
  });
};
```

Then you can use `then()` and `catch()`

Comment: Ahh many thanks for this. I had a feeling the loop was far too quick and everything was loaded after. I have never used then() and catch() but will def look into this. Thank You.